# Query result only that which is placed in the phtml file which belongs to the controller in ZF2

Tags: jquery, zend-framework2

I would like to ask some help regarding Zend Framework 2. I have an ajax call, I use jQuery, and I would like to insert the result of it into a particular part of the page. But the result contains other html tags.

I have this in my phtml file:

```
test content
```

I got this as a result which is the layout.phtml file and the view file content is inserted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        navbar
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        test content        </div> <!-- /container -->
    <div>
    <hr>
        <footer>
            <p>VSMoney Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How is possible to get back only that string, content, as an ajax call result, which is placed in the phtml file?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#dealing-with-layouts).

```
public function addOutingAction() {
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTerminal(true);
    return $view;
}
```